# How to write many to one relationship for below scenario hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

**User table**

```
id -pk
name
groupname
roleid
```

**UserGroup**

```
id -pk
name
description
roleid
```

In above tables, **groupname** and **roleid** is non-primary fields in **user table** has relationship with **name** and **roleid** in **usergroup table**

**Question here is** : how to write many to one relationship(user->usergroup) in user.hbm.xml

Answer (score 1):

Consider searching for "hibernate @OneToOne example".

Regarding foreign keys, consider keeping userGroup_id in user table instead of "groupname".

Comment: Thank you for answer. It is existing table, unfortunately we are not supposed to change it. actually it is not one to one mapping. it is many to one

Comment: Without changing the DB scheme it looks dark. You have to adapt the db to the new logic. Typically for an OneToMany relation is having a middle table just mapping one pk with the other pk. Like 'UserGroupUserRel' or something like that

Comment: sorry, we cant change the db scheme..is there any alternative solution without changing the db scheme